# Can you break this curse from Princes of the Apocalypse by being reduced to 0 hp?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, polymorph, curses, princes-of-the-apocalypse

In Princes of the Apocalypse, a player got hit with Ghaunadaur’s curse...  The rules for the curse state ([Temple of the Elder Elemental Eye, room F19](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/pota/temple-of-the-elder-elemental-eye#F19ThatWhichLurks); PotA, p. 121):

> The curse is like a *polymorph* spell, except it turns the offender into an ochre jelly that lacks the Split reaction. A *greater restoration* or *remove curse* spell ends this effect.

It says it's *like* a [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell... and *polymorph*'s description says that:

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies.

The part I'm hung up on is the *a greater restoration or remove curse spell ends this effect* part... does that mean ***only*** a *greater restoration* or *remove curse* spell ends the effect?  The wording almost suggests that this overrules the way *polymorph* works (since it's a curse).

Bottom line - does dropping to 0 hp end the curse?

Comment: I don't have access to this module, is your quote of the curse accurate in formatting?

Comment: It's a literal copy/paste of the only two sentences about it (will I get in trouble for pasting this?)... the sentences before it explain how the curse gets inflicted (the DC, type of save, etc).  There's no other information about it.

Comment: For future reference, [linking to D&D Beyond is perfectly fine](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7671/33707), even references that are not public.

Comment: Hmm... should I modify the title to say "polymorph-like curse"?  I'm beginning to think that distinction might be necessary...

Comment: @Hylianux There is no need, the question is fine as is. If such a distinction is necessary it is up to the answers to state/clarify that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No, it is not the spell *polymorph*

We don't know what "like the *polymorph* spell" means, but we do know that there are times when a specific mechanic is provided and when something similar is done.

There are many examples of creatures that can "polymorph" but that don't directly associate with the *polymorph* spell.  When that direct mechanic is used, WoTC typically uses language like "as if casting *polymorph*" with the associated italics.  Without the italics and language, I don't think we can assume that it works exactly the same way - especially when there is language on how to remove it that is different from *polymorph*.

With this curse, we don't know the extent of what the similarity is (other than changing your form and statistics), but we do know that unlike *polymorph*, the only way to end this is the language in the curse of:

> A greater restoration or remove curse spell ends this effect.

That above language is not in the actual spell *[polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)*, so those are the only things that can end this particular curse and not the standard ways of ending *polymorph* like HP to 0 or even dispel magic.

### Bestowing a Curse

The spell *[Bestow Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse)* utilizes similar removal techniques to this particular curse. The listed removal techniques for this spell are *Remove Curse* and *Greater Restoration's* specific bullet point.  However, *Dispel Magic* seems to remain an option for *Bestow Curse* where it is may not be an option for this particular curse. That's up to another question to resolve :)

For whether or not *Dispel Magic* would work on this curse requires determining if Ghaundaur's Curse is a magical effect or not. Based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical) it does appear that it is a magical effect as it is like a spell.

Comment: As I commented to Mr Spudtastic, it may be worth exploring the "bestow curse" thread from the "curse" piece of the name *Ghaunadaur’s curse* for the affliction/spell that turns creatures into an ooze.    Your call.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Great idea. I've added it - and then realized this generates another question about dispel magic.

Comment: Naut, all I can do is offer you an *evil grin* - my work is done here. :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [Here it is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138882/can-dispel-magic-remove-bestow-curse). I have a feeling it's obvious, but interesting enough to ask and clarify :)

Answer (score 18):

### By RAW, yes, dropping to 0 hp does end the curse

If the text you gave is, as stated in your comment, the only information given about the curse, then all the normal means of ending a *polymorph* spell will end the curse.

As quoted,

> The curse is like a *polymorph* spell, except it turns the offender into an ochre jelly that lacks the Split reaction.

Meaning, that it should otherwise be like the *Polymorph* spell in every way except those that are specifically noted.

> A *greater restoration* or *remove curse* spell ends this effect.

This doesn't exclude the normal means of ending the spell. It just adds an additional means to end the curse. It still maintains its "like a *polymorph* spell" status.

To add clarity, you can look at [T.J.L.'s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138873/48837) on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138872/48837). To summarize in his words, it's "Additive, Not Exclusive".

Comment: While I appreciate your reasoning, a lot of NPC abilities and module specific-details are not identical to what's in the PHB, and tend to be "custom made for this module" things.  I think that your answer would be improved if you explored the fact that the term "curse" is used in the spell description and show the relationship to the *bestow curse* spell ... your call.

Comment: Yeah, I'll admit, "like a polymorph spell" might not be as far-reaching as I think it is. If that is indeed the case, then Nautarch has provided a [good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138880/48837) for that line of reasoning.

Comment: Wouldn't the specific mention of "like polymorph" beat the general likeness this effect has with Bestow Curse?