# Can Dispel Magic remove the curse imposed by Bestow Curse?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, curses

*[Bestow Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse)* states in the spell description that *[Remove Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse)* can... remove the curse. We also have the mention in the description of *Greater Restoration* that states that the spell can remove a curse.

Can *[Dispel Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic)* also remove a curse imposed by *Bestow Curse*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Dispel Magic works

*Bestow Curse* is not an intantaneous effect, but one that requires concentration. Therefore the spell can be dispelled using *Dispel Magic* or similar means. The section about casting *Bestow Curse* at higher levels even mentions being eligible for dispelling for 9th level:

> If you use a 9th level spell slot, the spell lasts **until it is dispelled.**<sup>[PHB, p. 218]</sup>

Comment: I think it's worth noting that a spell is considered the level of the spell slot used and the mechanics for removing a curse from *Bestow Curse* 4th level+ are different than when cast at 3rd level, unless an equal level of *Dispel Magic* is cast.

Answer (score 4):

## It should be able to remove it

The description of *Dispel Magic* states:

> Choose one object, creature, or magic effect within range. Any spell
> of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

*Bestow Curse* is a 3rd Level Spell so it should apply here.
*Remove Curse* also ends the spell early, but RAW does not state this is the ONLY thing that will end it.

Comment: Don't forget that a spell is considered the level of the spell slot used to cast it.  This would need to be taken into account for both the *Bestow Curse* and *Dispel Magic* spells.